# java program reading my string input as a variable

Tags: java

can someone help me here? this is just a test, but when i run my program i am getting a cannot find symbol error, and it points the name i entered thinking it's a variable

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Employee{
    public String emp_name;
    public int emp_id;
    public double emp_salary;
    public int emp_phone;

    public Employee(String add_newName, int add_newID, double add_newSalary, int add_newPhone){
        emp_name = add_newName;
        emp_id = add_newID;
        emp_salary = add_newSalary;
        emp_phone = add_newPhone;
    }

    public Employee(int add_ID, int add_Phone){
        emp_name = "NULL";
        emp_id = add_ID;
        emp_salary = 0;
        emp_phone = add_Phone;
    }

    public double increaseSalary(double increase_amt){
        return emp_salary += increase_amt;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return emp_name;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Name of employee: " + emp_name + ",, " + "ID number of employee: " + emp_id + ",, " + "Employee salary: " + emp_salary + ",, " + "Employee phone: " + emp_phone;
    }

    public static void process(){
        Employee employee1 = new Employee(noel, 101, 5050.50, 1230987);
        Employee employee2 = new Employee(102, 5672389);
        System.out.println("Employee Information: " + employee1.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        process();
    }
}
```

The error is in the process method, where you see noel, java saying cannot find symbol for it...help?

Comment: `new Employee("noel", 101, 5050.50, 1230987);`

Comment: Try with "noel" as you declare it as a String variable

Answer (score 3):

change `noel` to `"noel"`

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee("noel", 101, 5050.50, 1230987);
```

without `""` java will assume it as variable

Answer (score 2):

Syntax for `String`s in Java is:

```
"Some String"
```

**Note the double quotes**. To fix your problem you will have to write `"noel"`.

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee("noel", 101, 5050.50, 1230987);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are creating employee by passing noel

```
  Employee employee1 = new Employee(noel, 101, 5050.50, 1230987);
```

It should be String as:

```
 Employee employee1 = new Employee("noel", 101, 5050.50, 1230987);
```